# Values from csv file in json via jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb4Pr.jpg)

I would like to put values ​​(numbers as text) from columns of a csv file automatically into a json file. From the result, I want to set a key and get this value back in a csv column. how can I tackle this in jupyter notebook?

Excuse me - I'm a bloody beginner.

```
import csv
with open('blabla.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "set a key and get this value back in a csv column"? Can you provide an example of your data and the desired output?

Comment: Hi @ilja I wanted to put a value from a csv into a specified url/query string to get information from this url. I added a picture of the code in my frist comment.

Comment: @Janexdoe [Don't post code and exception using images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Your string on line 4 is not quoted by `"` or `'`, also your requested url returned empty json. And I don't see relationship between your asked question with your posted code. I had to type the url **manually** to reproduce the problem, please do not post code in images.

Comment: @knh190 oh, sorry for posting an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
with open('blabla1.csv', newline='') as f:    
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        url = "http://blabla2.php?isbn=" + str(row[1]) + "&format=json"  
        print(url)
```

Comment: you are new to StackOverflow, at StackOverflow we normally accept the answers that helped us and do not repost and accept the answers ourself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your were pretty close.

bla.csv:

```
3-85460-115-8
4-85460-115-8
5-85460-115-8
6-85460-115-8
```

Code:

```
import csv
with open('bla.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        url = "http://data.bib.uni-mannheim.de/malibu/isbn/gbv.php?isbn=" + str(row[0]) + "&format=json"
        print(url)
        thing = urlretrieve(url)
        # Do what you want to do with the thing... :-)
```

output:

```
http://data.bib.uni-mannheim.de/malibu/isbn/gbv.php?isbn=3-85460-115-8&format=json
http://data.bib.uni-mannheim.de/malibu/isbn/gbv.php?isbn=4-85460-115-8&format=json
http://data.bib.uni-mannheim.de/malibu/isbn/gbv.php?isbn=5-85460-115-8&format=json
http://data.bib.uni-mannheim.de/malibu/isbn/gbv.php?isbn=6-85460-115-8&format=json
```

If you have any trouble, feel free to comment. And like knh190 said, please post code as text not as images next time. :-)

Comment: Dear @ilja thank you so so much - it worked! Wow!Now, I'm gonna try the next step - getting the value of some keys in the json strings :-)

Comment: @Janexdoe, happy to help. :-) Please consider accepting or upvoting the solution if it helped you or you liked it.